# how to reach a component in a tab when my app  has several same tabs?(how to determin the active tab?)

Tags: java, swing, tabs, components

I have written an app which connects to several Databases (Check the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740048/how-to-create-several-tabs-dynamically)). and I have respectively several tabs containing query panels with INPUT textfields. now I want to reach the specific textfield in a selected tab to make query of the relevant database... please let me now how I can reach it?

I should mention that I have created a class for the JPanel which should be added to the jTabbedPane as following:

```
package testGUI_V2;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;
import static testGUI_V2.DialogBoxTest.service;

public class TabbedPane {
private String state;
private JLabel jLabel3;
private JTextField jTextField2;
private JTextPane jTextPane1;
private JButton jButton4;
private static int item = 0;
private int tabIndex;

public JPanel CreatePanel(){
    state = service.toUpperCase();
    tabIndex = item;
    JPanel inst1 = new JPanel();
    String tabTitle =String.format("Query Panel %d",item+1);
    inst1.setSize(302, 138);
    inst1.setLayout(null);
    inst1.setBorder(BorderFactory
                    .createTitledBorder(BorderFactory
                    .createEtchedBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED), tabTitle));
    inst1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(321, 108));

        jLabel3 = new JLabel("Employee ID", SwingConstants.LEFT);
        inst1.add(jLabel3);
        jLabel3.setBounds(12, 15, 103, 26);
        jLabel3.setVisible(true);

        jTextField2 = new JTextField();
        inst1.add(jTextField2);
        jTextField2.setVisible(true);
        jTextField2.setBounds(109, 15, 93, 30);

        jTextPane1 = new JTextPane();
        inst1.add(jTextPane1);
        jTextPane1.setBounds(6, 50, 307, 50);

        jButton4 = new JButton("Search");
        inst1.add(jButton4);
        jButton4.setVisible(true);
        jButton4.setBounds(231, 15, 82, 29);
        //jButton4.addActionListener(search);

        item++;
        return inst1;
}
public JTextField getQueryJTextField(){
    return jTextField2;
}
public String getPanelState(){
    return state;
}
public int getTabIndex(){
    return tabIndex;
}
}
```

Moreover, the below codes are related to the "Connect" button which calls the createPanel() method of TabbedPane Class:

```
            {
            jButton2 = new JButton();
            getContentPane().add(jButton2);
            jButton2.setText("Connect");
            jButton2.setBounds(229, 50, 90, 29);
            jButton2.setVisible(false);
            jButton2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    LinkedFrame inst2 = new LinkedFrame(inst, true);
                    inst2.setLocationRelativeTo(rootPane);
                    inst2.setVisible(true);
                    if (Connector.getProcessStatue()) {
                        TabbedPane inst= new TabbedPane();
                        jPanel3.setVisible(true);
                        tabbedPane1.addTab(connectionItem,null ,info.get(inst.getTabIndex()));
                        info.add(inst.CreatePanel());
                        System.out.println(inst.getPanelState());
                        jButton2.setVisible(false);
                        jButton3.setVisible(true);
                        setSize(342, 265);
                    }

                }
            });
        }
```

please also let me know if my strategy is true?

Comment: Can you clarify how this question differs from your previous question on this topic, [how to create several tabs dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740048/how-to-create-several-tabs-dynamically) Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: In my previous question I was looking for a solution to create several tabs in my app....it is solved and I have them in my APP but now I cannot reach the textfield in my panels when there are more than one tabs...:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I almost always create subclasses of JPanel for my GUI programming. When I need to access components for later use, I also make sure to keep references to these components in my JPanel class and provide accessor methods for the data I wish to retrieve:

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
  private JTextField myTextField = new JTextField();

  String getText() {
    return myTextField.getText();
  }
}
```

I also create subclasses of JFrame to hold my custom panels. And as with the JPanel subclass, I will keep private references to instances of my custom panels:

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
  private MyPanel myPanel = new MyPanel();

  public MyFrame() {
    this.add(myPanel);

    JButton someButton = new JButton("Do It!");
    someButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        String text = MyFrame.this.myPanel.getText();

        // Do something with the text
      }
    });
  }
}
```

The class containing an instance of MyPanel could be anything, not just a JFrame. The basic idea applies, though: subclass Swing components and keep references of components that you need to access after they are created.

Comment: thanks for your help....please take this into consideration that there should be several Tabs and each tab has its own search button...so I have to create panels in such a way that I could distinguish between each panel and reach its own SEARCH button...please give me a solution how to handle this issue?!!!

Comment: Please edit your question or ask a new one to who us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Are the controls on each tab the same or do they differ?

Comment: Do you mean you don't want to be able to go back to the previous tab or that you want to, but your current implementation doesn't allow it?

Comment: that is right, I want to be able to use the previous tabs but my current code does not allow me....I can send you my runnable Jar file to understand the problem better or all my codes and classes.

Comment: @msc87 The most obvious solution is to add a "Previous" or perhaps a "Cancel" button that allows you to go back to a previous tab. Of course, this is entirely a design issue depending on what your requirements are.